# How to export csv file from a particular location and made available for download?

Tags: php, csv, download

Due to Speed issues and threading I have generated a CSV file in a particular location

```
Admin - CSV - xyz.csv
```

I want to write a program to just made it available on view. I know how to make a tmp csv and use header function for making downloadable the csv, But I am looking for the approach which only take this xyz.csv available for download on a click. Please Help!

I read out lot of examples but not find exact answer for my question.

As per recommended I have tried.

```
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');

        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="data.csv"');

        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'csv');

        $objWriter->save('php://output');

        exit;
```

Comment: Perhaps show a small test case for what it is that you have tried already?

Comment: Use the same headers as you would for a tmp csv, but use readfile() instead of building a tmp csv

Comment: @MarkBaker - I have tried readfile() like - readfile("abx.csv"); But it has printed all the html page with csv content .. its not come for download.

Comment: @MarkBaker - Do you pointing something from here 

$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($filename);
    
   $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);

Comment: Now you seem to be exacerbating your problem..... and confusing the question.... now it's completely unclear what you're trying to do! are you trying to create a file? are you trying to display a file? If you're just working with a simple csv file, why are you using PHPExcel (unnecessary for a trivial task)?

Comment: If the file already exists, then readfile() can be used to send it simply and easily to the browser; send the appropriate headers for a csv file; don't send any other output! Simples